# Avoid deleting data from the database while using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

For some reason, I want to use rspec without recreating the test database.

Presently using `rake spec` or `rake db:test:prepare` recreates the database, reloads the data.

Is there any configuration by which I can avoid that.

I tried using `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false` in `rails_helper.rb`, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use DatabaseCleaner with transaction strategy
https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner

Comment: Thanks Pavel,but I don't want the data to get deleted by any strategy since we don't have Test Database setup, we are looking to use Dev Database.Any other way?

Comment: So, if you use `:transaction` strategy for database cleaner. then all changes during the suite running will be reverted, and all pre-seeded data, or your dev db should stay.